# Python - Download Images from a list of urls in a csv and rename images from custom list

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to download a group of images from a site and rename them on the way in. I have a list of 30 image urls in a csv. They are all in column A like:

```
A
site.com/img1.jpg
site.com/img2.jpg
```

EDIT: This csv is saved as a 'windows comma separated' csv.

I built a script that would go through the csv one by one and rename the file based on where the img counter was at:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
import csv

with open ('image urls.csv') as images:
    images = csv.reader(images)
    img_count = 1
    for image in images:
        urlretrieve(image[0],
                'images/image_{0}.jpg'.format(img_count)) 
        img_count += 1
```

The script works well and saves all images to the 'images' folder in that directory.

However, I also have a list of custom names for each image that I'd like to use to rename each image as it is downloaded. The names are not currently in column B when I run this script but if added, my csv would look like:

```
A                    B
site.com/img1.jpg     Trees
site.com/img2.jpg     Ocean Waves
```

How can I designate column B as the image name rather than just the current image counter number?

Comment: `urlretrieve(image[0], "images/{}.jpg".format(image[1]))`?

Comment: @abukaj why would it matter if there are spaces in the file name? Python handles them just fine.

Comment: @MattDMo depends on individual preferences; also some scripts (e.g. `ls` based) do not handle them properly

Comment: Hmm.. ran this and did not get an error but no images downloaded to local folder or target 'images' folder.

Comment: Update: The above code worked. For some reason I had written the list of names in column C rather than B. Once in B, the script worked perfectly.

Comment: @abukaj you should [never](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) be parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: @MattDMo I know that but some people do not. It is why i tend to avoid spaces in filenames. Also, it is easier to type the nami in console (no quotes/escapes necessary)